# Unable to get max id from database

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I tried to get the max id from the database. However, it returns me the error

> `undefined index: id in $maxID=$rowsInit["id"]; and $response["maxID"] = $rowsInit["id"];`

This is my code

```
if ($_POST['maxID'] == 0) {
    $queryInit = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM trade";
    try {
        $stmtInit = $db->prepare($queryInit);
        $resultInit = $stmtInit->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = $ex;
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $rowsInit = $stmtInit->fetchAll();

    if ($rowsInit) {
        $maxID = $rowsInit["id"];
        $response["maxID"] = $rowsInit["id"];
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No Trade Available!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
} else {
    $maxID = $_POST['maxID'];
}
```

There is a column call id in my trade table. I don't know which part is wrong. Maybe I miss some part.

Comment: $queryInit="SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM trade";

try to change your query.

Comment: @scarletwitch I have changed the query but still receive same error

Comment: can you show the `$response` and `$rowsInit` ?

Comment: @lighter $response["maxID"] is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this to

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM trade
```

this

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM trade
```

**And**

change this to

```
$maxID=$rowsInit["id"];
```

this

```
$maxID=$rowsInit[0]["id"]; # or  $maxID=$rowsInit[0]->id
```

As I know Fetched data indexed with `0`. [Check these examples](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchall-examples)

---

> **If Failed add this `print_r($rowsInit);die;` next to  `if ($rowsInit) {` and check how it placed in array**

Comment: can you add SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM trade to your answer also? Then I can accept it as final answer

Comment: @downvoer please specify a reason? don't be a rude/ **jealous**

Comment: This answer doesn't explain what is wrong in the code, why it doesn't work. While your suggestions indeed solve the problem, what are the readers learning from this answer? They learn that they can throw their problems on [so] and somebody will solve them.

Comment: @axiac was mentioned whats wrong here `$maxID=$rowsInit[0]["id"]` **its error on access method**.  So what else to be posted ??

Comment: @axiac ***They learn that they can throw their problems on Stack Overflow and somebody will solve them*** indeed. We are here to share our knowledge to solve their problem. If you said NO, then leave Stack and write articles will make you happy :P

Answer (score 4):

Alias the function call as `id`:

```
$queryInit="SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM trade";
```

You also need to fetch first row's data. so provide row index as well. Try

```
$rowsInit[0]["id"]
```

Comment: Same error, undefined index : id in line 22 and 23 which is $maxID=$rowsInit["id"]; and $response["maxID"] = $rowsInit["id"];

Comment: You also need to fetch first row's data. so provide row index as well. Try `$rowsInit[0]["id"]`

Answer (score 1):

PDO is much more than everyone is taking it for. Beside omniprescent fetchAll() it has methods to get the result in a dozen other formats, including a single scalar value, so you won't have to alter your query as it suggested in other answers. So actually you need just **one single line** to get the max id:

```
 $id = $pdo->query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM trade")->fetchColumn();
```

note that you don't have to prepare a query if there are no placeholders in it.

What is more important, your idea on the [error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) is also wrong. You should never ever leak the actual system error message outside. Only a generic error message should be returned.

```
try {
    if ($_POST['maxID'] == 0) {
        $maxID = $pdo->query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM trade")->fetchColumn();
        if (!$rowsInit) {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No Trade Available!";
            die(json_encode($response));
        }
    } else {
        $maxID = $_POST['maxID'];
    }

    // here goes your code to get the response

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    log_error($ex);
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Server error";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
```

here you are wrapping your whole code in a global try catch block that will handle not only PDO exceptions **but also any other exception** that may occur.

Answer (score 0):

The query reads:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM trade
```

Why do you expect to have a column named `id` in the result set? There is no such column in `SELECT` clause. There is only the `MAX(id)` expression and its column in the resultset is named `MAX(id)` unless you provide an [alias](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) for it:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM trade
```

Read more about the syntax of the [`SELECT` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

`$rowsInit` still doesn't have an `id` index because of:

```
$rowsInit = $stmtInit->fetchAll();
```

[PDOStatement::fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns an array of rows. You should either use `$rowsInit = $stmtInit->fetchAll()[0];` or, even better, use [PDOStatement::fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) to get only the first row (the result set contains exactly one row, anyway):

```
$rowsInit = $stmtInit->fetch();
```